# Set no to Allow this site to appear in search results using XMl and c#?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, custom-list, xml, properties

I need to set No for **Allow items from this list to appear in search results?** for my custom list, [image]

so I achieved this by following PowerShell scripts

```
//Get the list which was created
SPList spList = spWeb.Lists[Customlist];
spList.NoCrawl = true; // Not allow items to appear in search results
spList.NoCrawl = false; // Allow items to appear in search results
```

But I need to achieve this by XML and c#. I mean I am creating the custom list using XML and c#, I need to set that false while list creation, so I am not sure about that property name in XML. Please advise me to achieve this.

Comment: can you share the xml that you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be NoCrawl.

```
<ListTemplate
  AllowDeletion = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  AllowEveryoneViewItems = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  AlwaysIncludeContent = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  BaseType = "0" | "1" | "3" |"4" | "5"
  CacheSchema = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Catalog = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Category = "Libraries" | "Communications" | "Tracking" | 
    "Custom Lists"
  Default = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Description = "Text"
  DisableAttachments = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  DisallowContentTypes = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  DisplayName = "Text"
  DocumentAsEnclosure = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  DocumentTemplate = "Integer"
  DontSaveInTemplate = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  EditPage = "Text"
  EnableModeration = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  EnablePeopleSelector = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  EnableResourceSelector = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  FeatureId = "Text"
  FolderCreation = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Hidden = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  HiddenList = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Image = "URL"
  MultipleTypes = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  MustSaveRootFiles = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Name = "Text"
  NewPage = "Text"
  NoCrawl = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  OnQuickLaunch = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Path = "Text"
  RootWebOnly = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  SecurityBits = "Text"
  Sequence = "Integer"
  SetupPath = "Text"
  SyncType = "Text"
  Type = "Integer"
  Unique = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  UseRootFolderForNavigation = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  VersioningEnabled = "TRUE" | "FALSE">
</ListTemplate>
```

Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462947.aspx for more details